# Can I send messages to another user using push notification service in windows phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7

Can I send messages to another user using push notification service in windows phone?
I am thinking of using MPNS.the reason to this is users should be able to exchange small info one to one at a time.

Comment: Like a text message or Twitter or Facebook messenger or Snapchat?

Comment: Yes, it's a simple text message.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, windows phone registers for push notifications and receives special url. If phone A receives url and passes it to phone B somehow (via cloud service or smth.), then phone B can send push notifications to phone A using this url.